# Parse kit crashing on xcode 4.5

Tags: ios, xcode

i have used parse kit in my project and it works fine. The original project was made in xcode 4.2.1. works fine on iphone 4s and iOS 5.

The problem is when i opened the same project in xcode 4.5 and installed it on device it crashed while using method

```
t = [PKTokenizer tokenizerWithString:moveString];
```

it crashes. the error msg is
**dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _objc_setProperty_nonatomic
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/9BE9D9FB-278D-45FD-B5EB-62FC0A162DC6/Mchess.app/Mchess
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib**   I am still back tracing it into parse kit but any guidance will be helpful

Thanks

Comment: What is this mchess app?  Is it new?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your deployment target isn't set correctly; see [this page](https://github.com/PrimaryFeather/Sparrow-Framework/pull/1078).

Comment: @trojanefoe you have helped me many times i am very grateful.   Pls join this group will be grt to have you there  http://www.facebook.com/groups/360017687365706/

Comment: @amar OK done - I'm really an OSX developer, but what the heck.